# Android import java library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good Day! 
I've created new project in Android Studio and imported Bitcoinj.jar. Now i want to import ExtLibj from Samourai project. (https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/ExtLibJ) (it's an extension above bitcoinj)

But i can't import it as module.

If i create new module and add files to this folders, 
i can't import them as (`import com.samourai.wallet.hd.*`)

How i can import this library in to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Add this in your project level build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2.Add this in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.Samourai-Wallet:ExtLibJ:Tag'
}
```